# Oracle 11g Windows lost SYS password

Tags: oracle

I inherited an old Oracle DB and the previous IT person did not pass along the SYS password. It is Release 11.2.0.1.0 on Windows 2016. My OS user is in the ora_dba group but I am still unable to connect with **/ as sysdba**. It gives the error **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**. I checked the sqlnet.ora file and it has SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(NTS) which should allow me to connect without a password because I am a member of the ora_dba Windows group. All I need is to get access and reset the SYS password to something new for my own use. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried all permutations of sqlplus "/ as sysdba", sqlplus '/ as sysdba' and sqlplus / as sysdba? set ORACLE_SID=<SID> is also something to consider to make sure you connect to the right instance.

Comment: you can use orapwd utility from the command prompt to set a new sys password. The default password file is stored in ORACLE_HOME\DATABASE\PWDsid.ORA